# How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, jackson

My json look like :

```
[
   {
      "schedule":[
         {
            "amount":19.98,
            "due_at":null,
            "identifier":"1549b45ff814e181dcbb983a02b35e9b3dd276fc-1",
            "paid_at":"2012-01-24",
            "status":"paid"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "schedule":[
         {
            "amount":24.68,
            "due_at":null,
            "identifier":"1549fdfdf814e181dcbb983a02b35e9b3dd276fc-1",
            "paid_at":"2012-08-14",
            "status":"paid"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My schedule model:

```
public class Schedule {
    public double amount;
    public String due_at;
    public String identifier;
    public String paid_at;
    public String status;
}
```

My schedules model:

```
public class Schedules extends HashMap<String, ArrayList<Schedule>>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

for now I use:

```
ListSchedules objectMapper.readValue = (jp, new TypeReference <Schedules> () {});
```

But it does not work, can someone tell me the way to go

Comment: It looks like an array of arrays, is it correct?

Comment: why not wrap the json use `{}` and use `List` to deserialise the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify to something like below

For Array of Objects

```
Schedule[] objects = objectMapper.readValue(jp, Schedule[].class);
```

For List of Objects

```
    List<Schedule> objects = 
objectMapper.readValue(jp, new TypeReference<List<Schedule>>(){})
```

*Assuming `jp` is jason text

Comment: if I want use objects from your code a nullpointer exception is throws

Comment: forget my comment, my json was invalide, thank you for your help!